# Выбор рандомно случайных чисел

Tags: php

Есть 2 массива. В обоих n-ое количество чисел. 
Мне в базе данных надо случайно сопоставить эти числа. 
Н-р: массив1[0] --- массив2[3]

Делал с помощью функции rand, но с помощью этого способа код зацикливается надолго(никогда не дожидался). Думаю из-за того, что функция rand не может попасть в конце в определенное число. 
Может есть более оптимальное решение?

```
 for($i = 1; $i<$count_massiv_number; $i++)
        {

            while($rand_mission = rand(1,count($massiv_mission))){ if(!in_array($rand_mission,$except_mission)) break;}

             while($rand_number = rand(1,count($massiv_number))){ if(!in_array($rand_number,$except_number)) break;}

            $for_massiv_mission = $massiv_mission[$rand_mission];
            $for_number_mission = $massiv_number[$rand_number];
            $quer = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO spisok (`id_name`, `id_game`, `id_mission`, `number`) 
                            Values ('$id_user', '$id_game', '$for_massiv_mission', '$for_number_mission' ) ");

            unset($massiv_mission[$rand_mission]);array_push($except_mission, $rand_mission);
            unset($massiv_number[$rand_number]);  array_push($except_number, $rand_number);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался.
Нужно было не unset использовать, а array_splice;